# Possible allow cookies for wp-admin, but not front end while using Varnish?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, cookies, varnish

I'm running Varnish in front of my Wordpress site. To increase my cache hit stats I blocked cookies in my varnish configuration in default.vcl

```
# Drop any cookies sent to Wordpress.
sub vcl_recv {
    unset req.http.cookie;
}
# Drop any cookies Wordpress tries to send back to the client.
sub vcl_fetch {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}
```

I believe this is what is keeping me from logging in to wp-admin right now. I am continually redirected back to the login page. Any idea what kind of filter I need to pass into that cookie blocker? I'm not familiar with this configuration language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to NOT drop cookies if the URL is from the admin section.

Like this:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "(wordpress_|wp-)") {
        return (pass); // If WP cookies exist, do not cache
    } else {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }
}
```

?